# 500 error Отдача динамической карты сайта в nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, веб-сервер, sitemap

Доброго времени. У меня карта сайта генерируется, поэтому в nginx я не могу указать к ей путь. Скажите пожалуйста, как мне исправить это, что бы nginx распознавал ссылку site.ru/sitemap.xml?

Заранее спасибо :)

**Отредактировано:
Записи в логах**

```
2017/09/06 15:24:06 [crit] 3124#0: accept4() failed (24: Too many open files)
2017/09/06 15:24:06 [alert] 3124#0: *4068 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.124.139.xxx, server: xxx.by, request: "GET /sitemap.xml HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx/site-map.xml", host: "xxx.by"
```

Comment: Это забота не nginx, а джанги, не?

Comment: @andreymal так на продакшне все работает, а с nginx выбивает ошибку

Comment: Может создать новую директиву для `/sitemap.xml` и в ней прописать перенаправление к django (`proxy_pass localhost:port` или что-то похожее)?

Comment: @ArtemNester как устроен продакшн тогда?

Comment: @andreymal в каком смысле как? я генерирую карту сайта с помощью django.contrib.sitemaps. Потом весь результат передаю по ссылке /sitemap.xml

Comment: @ArtemNester окей, какой конфиг nginx тогда?

Comment: А, стоп, 500 error? Ну тогда надо логи читать же

Comment: @andreymal отредактировал. на счет конфига: в этом и заключается моя сложность, что я не знаю что там писать, потому что данные генерируются на одну ссылку,а файл вроде как и не создается

Comment: @ArtemNester в этом вся и сложность: ответить на Ваш вопрос не видя конфигов и логов ngnix не возможно.

Comment: @ArtemNester Мой вам совет, файл сайтмапа генерировать только по крону, незачем его на лету генерировать джангой, зачем вам такая нагрузка лишняя. Тогда в nginx просто прописывается локэйшен до этого файла и все. Сайтмап должен быстро отдаваться поисковикам, а так он видимо у вас долго генерируется из за чего не хватает соединений